# Algorithm to compute Gamma function

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, special-functions, gamma-function

The question is simple. I would like to implement the Gamma function in my calculator written in C; however, I have not been able to find an easy way to programmatically compute an approximation to arbitrary precision.

Is there a good algorithm to compute approximations of the Gamma function?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an algorithm for its complex domain or just for real numbers?

Comment: complex would be better

Comment: For reals it in is the [GNU C library](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_393.html) (haven't checked if it is mandated by the standard).

Comment: @vonbrand: not to arbitrary precision, though.

Comment: State of the art: Fredrik Johansson, "Arbitrary-precision computation of the gamma function." arXiv preprint [arXiv:2109.08392](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.08392) (2021).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like the Lanczos approximation will suit my needs : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [This note](http://my.fit.edu/~gabdo/gamma.txt) should be of interest.

Answer (score 5):

It is now part of the C++11 standard library.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tgamma

Comment: What you link to is the C++ interface to the standard C library.

Comment: This is not to arbitrary precision, though.

Answer (score 5):

Take the divergent series

$$\hat J_\nu(z):=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi z}}\left\{p(z)\cos\left(z-\dfrac{2\nu+1}{4}\pi\right)-q(z)\sin\left(z-\dfrac{2\nu+1}{4}\pi\right)\right\}$$

with

$$p(z):=1-\dfrac{(4\nu^2-1^2)(4\nu^2-3^2)}{2!(8z)^2}+\dfrac{(4\nu^2-1^2)(4\nu^2-3^2)(4\nu^2-5^2)(4\nu^2-7^2)}{4!(8z)^4}-+\dots$$

and

$$q(z):=\dfrac{(4\nu^2-1^2)}{1!(8z)^1}-\dfrac{(4\nu^2-1^2)(4\nu^2-3^2)(4\nu^2-5^2)}{3!(8z)^3}+-\dots$$

For the Bessel function $J_\nu(z)$ we get the estimation

$$\left\vert J_\nu(z)-\hat J_\nu^{(k)}(z)\right\vert\le O\left(z^{-k-3/2}\right)$$

for $\vert z\vert\ge1$ and $Re\{z\}\ge0$ with the partial sum $\hat J_\nu^{(k)}(z)$ whose last summand has the term

$$\dfrac{(4\nu^2-1^2)\cdots(4\nu^2-(2k-1)^2)}{k!(8z)^k}.$$

The Bessel function $J_\nu(z)$ can be calculated to

$$J_\nu(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!\Gamma(\nu+j+1)}\left(\dfrac{z}{2}\right)^{\nu+2j}.$$

With $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ we obtain

$$J_\nu(z)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!(\nu+1)\cdots(\nu+j)}\left(\dfrac{z}{2}\right)^{\nu+2j}.$$

Take

$$K_\nu(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!(\nu+1)\cdots(\nu+j)}\left(\dfrac{z}{2}\right)^{\nu+2j}.$$

Then we obtain

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{K_\nu\left(n\pi+\dfrac{2\nu+1}{4}\pi\right)}{\hat J_\nu^{(k)}\left(n\pi+\dfrac{2\nu+1}{4}\pi\right)}=\Gamma(\nu+1)$$

and the gamma function drops out of the game.

As an example we get for $\nu=0.5$, $k=10$ and $z=4\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$$\dfrac{K_{0.5}\left(z\right)}{\hat J_{0.5}^{(10)}\left(z\right)}=0.88622692546003057$$

and

$$\dfrac{K_{0.5}\left(z+0.1\right)}{\hat J_{0.5}^{(10)}\left(z+0.1\right)}=0.88622692544073867.$$

But

$$\Gamma\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}= 0.88622692545275794.$$

Because the series $\hat J_{0.5}(z)$ terminates for $\nu=\dfrac{1}{2}$ we even have $\hat J_{0.5}(z)=J_{0.5}(z)$ and the difference is only due to the precision of our calculation that was made with the type $\mathbf{double}$ (or System.Double) in C#.

For $\nu=0.25$, $k=10$ and $z=4\pi+\dfrac{3\pi}{8}$ we get

$$\dfrac{K_{0.25}\left(z\right)}{\hat J_{0.25}^{(10)}\left(z\right)}=0.90640247708308364\approx\Gamma(1.25)=\dfrac{1}{4}\Gamma(0.25)$$

and for $\nu=0.75$, $k=10$ and $z=4\pi+\dfrac{5\pi}{8}$ we get

$$\dfrac{K_{0.75}\left(z\right)}{\hat J_{0.75}^{(10)}\left(z\right)}=0.91906252683450718\approx\Gamma(1.75)=\dfrac{3}{4}\Gamma(0.75).$$

With

$$\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)$$

we obtain

$$(4\cdot 0.90640247708308364)\cdot(4\cdot 0.91906252683450718\,/\,3)-\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\pi/4}=0.000000000065\dots$$

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked a similar question yesterday. I thought of replacing $e^{-t}$ by a series.
$$\Gamma (z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt \approx \sum_{j=0}^{a} \frac{(-1)^j b^{j+z}}{(j + z) j !} . \text{Choose } a > b ,$$ but as J. M. points out, I should have checked this a bit better. Take great care in the choice of $a, b$.

Comment: Have you *tried* implementing this? :)

Comment: Not with more than one $z$. It can be very inaccurate depending on the choice of $a, b$. Now that I've tried a few more $z$, it looks like $a = b z^2$ is about right, but $b$ must also be chosen not too far from $z$. Example: $z = 6.6$, $b=2 \times z$, $a = b z^2$. This is only a guess!

Answer (score 2):

Try Nemes' approximation:

$$\ln ( \Gamma( x ) ) = \frac12 \ln( 2 \pi ) + \left( x - \frac12 \right) \ln( x ) - x + \frac x2  
                       \ln\left( x \sinh\left( \frac1x \right) + \frac 1 {810 x^6} \right) $$

The last term, $\dfrac1 { 810 x^6}$ is an error-checking term and may be eliminated from your calculations.

[Here is my reference](http://www.rskey.org/CMS/index.php/the-library/11).

Comment: Error-checking? No. Its a term used to increase precision. It has nothing to do with error checking. This isnt a binary transmission or whatever youre thinking.

Comment: For small values, this is only a very rough approximation. E.g., for x=1, the LHS is 0, but the RHS is 0.00015268924587. The error relative to scipy.special.gammaln is roughly proportional to x^{-4} for x in [1,3].  On the other hand, it's about four times faster.

Answer (score 1):

How about interpolation of the numbers in a look-up table featuring numbers drawn from a graph of the curve you are looking for?
If you have the program Stella, you can literally shape by hand a curve that you desire, and it produces the numbers to be added to the table.

Comment: The domain of the Gamma function is the entire complex plane. You cannot use a lookup table for functions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lanczos approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation) to implement it. The C# implementation looks like:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test cases for the SpecialFunctionGamma method
        double[] testValues = { 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 };
        foreach (double value in testValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Gamma({value}) = {SpecialFunctionGamma(value)}");
        }
    }

    //Lanczos Approximation for Gamma Function
    private static double SpecialFunctionGamma(double z)
    {
        double[] p =
        {
            676.5203681218851,
            -1259.1392167224028,
            771.32342877765313,
            -176.61502916214059,
            12.507343278686905,
            -0.13857109526572012,
            9.9843695780195716e-6,
            1.5056327351493116e-7
        };
        if (z < 0.5)
            return Math.PI / (Math.Sin(Math.PI * z) * SpecialFunctionGamma(1 - z));
        z -= 1;
        double x = 0.99999999999980993;
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            x += p[i] / (z + i + 1);
        }

        double t = z + p.Length - 0.5;
        return Math.Sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * Math.Pow(t, z + 0.5) * Math.Exp(-t) * x;
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPJbtswEL37KwZBD1IdK1xEUoLjQ1G0RYEECOCiPQQ5sApjE7AlVaRT14a/3R3Kq4xkDqOh@ObNysINiqox2@3C2XIC43/Om/mw1ytm2jl4aKpJo@e9dQ9QnNfeFvBa2We417aMnG/Q6fEJdDNxcYvZIYPc3MAP4zwU2hkHL1UDfmpgXJvC6tnXRVl4W5Xf9HyuYW78tHo@ej5Xi98zg7Qe/X/q2QL9R7AGkohroAkJCi0WLBYsHiwerDRYIigZlEoIbIZHYkzC6GIK0S4CvAZusOVZoPgIPlUS5HNVumpmkl@N9ebOlib6cNUmH61blk0cUnyruqi9jzdX8SmRTW@ne7tG3emyWFUOPtV1Uy3tXAfntmW7/hz4Wnjd2FftzWEa@1LejLy/W12O5tjgGkbv1CuVTAQjXGaU0SwT9LpzPaBM5AnlOaNSMZYSlnUBStGEM56yTCklBaf8kgADSCoIy6lkNCUi7wIoTpYonnKmMpnJnIgLAoLhM6EoyQWTQjFCWReRJ3mWcpkLlRGKmkozkBdBMIaQGIILmuacBog6Tek0MPsC0QpuwwrGHYbG@EVT4nPw0@ThO9xA1JpjfB2Hfx9xAKjenBCFAd6ebcYKBiOgw4tRwRK3iyT5mWQkz3lntSGypQcbkEP83EKd3Jly4qd46vffW@wl9EdQP9qnkPsK@ujZB9rZ1ctkPIYIyAM/1oB9OXmc92T8p/ERw/L33YiPZvU38tctT2jq4feXZR0NfDguh/tHstlu/wM)