# Can Euler's reflection formula be used to calculate $\Gamma (1/3)$?

Tags: closed-form, gamma-function

Can [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) be used to calculate $\Gamma (1/3)$? (That is, to express in in some closed form.) When trying to apply it, I am always falling in a loop.

Comment: do you mean $\Gamma(1/3)$ ??

Comment: Do you mean how it is calculated in practice?

Comment: $\Gamma(1/3)$ is a transcendental number algebraically independent of $\pi$; no really explicit formula for this number is known. All that is explained, say, in Wikipedia. What is your question exactly?

Comment: I wonder how is it calculated gamma (1/3) using the formula of Euler reflection and also like to see a demonstration gamma (1/3) = 2.6 ...

Comment: This [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169184/estimating-the-gamma-function-to-high-precision-efficiently) may help.

Comment: Are you asking about a pencil-and-paper calculation?  This business about "falling in a loop" suggests you are applying [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) repeatedly and expecting to get something new from that alone.

Comment: I think you are not understanding my question. 
Would like someone to prove me ajudadesse Gamma (1/3) = 2.6 .... using the formula of reflection. =)

Answer (score 5):

Although Euler's reflection formula is satisfied by the gamma function:

$$ \Gamma(x) \Gamma(1-x) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi x}, \;\; \forall x \not\in \mathbb{Z} $$

and this suffices to determine $\pm\;\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$, it does not define all values of the function $\Gamma(x)$.  In particular there are many functions that satisfy the reflection formula above, but which have differing values at $x=\frac{1}{3}$.

One easily sees that setting $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in the reflection formula gives us $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{\pi}{1}$, so $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$ if we know this value is positive (clear from the [integral definition of the gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition)).

However consider any positive real base $a \gt 0$ and define $f_a(x) = a^{x - \frac{1}{2}}$.

Then $f_a(x) f_a(1-x) = a^0 = 1$, and one easily verifies that $f_a(x) \Gamma(x)$ will satisfy Euler's reflection formula for noninteger $x$.  By varying $a$ we can obtain any positive value for $f_a(\frac{1}{3}) \Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$ that we like.

Note also that substituting $-\Gamma(x)$ for $\Gamma(x)$ in the reflection formula leaves the product $\Gamma(x) \Gamma(1-x)$ unchanged, so this is another demonstration that the reflection formula alone does not define the gamma function.

The integral definition of $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$ can give precise approximations as the link in Raymond Manzoni's Comment explains, and Grigory M's Comment [pointing you to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#General_rational_arguments) should provide more rapid approximations of this [transcendental number](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3253.pdf).