# Finding Factorial using Integral Definition

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, factorial

$n! = \int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{-x}{x}^{n} \,dx$

How can we find $400!$?

$400! = \int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{-x}{x}^{400} \,dx$

Integration by parts is **way** too complicated, what are the other options?

Comment: Depends entirely on what you mean by "finding." The notation $400!$ is a precise definition of a number. To approximate its size, Stirlings. To factor it correctly, Legendre's Theorem on prime powers in factorials. In case you don't know, $400! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots 400.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration by parts will only tell you that $400!=400\cdot 399!$, which we know from the definition of a factorial; in fact, this is one way to prove the integral definition. Using the integral to calculate the factorial is rarely the most efficient method, particularly when $n$ is an integer, as in your example. The fastest method of calculating a factorial with integer $n$ is through its prime factors, which are easily calculable by the formula $n!$ divides $p$ precisely $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \log_p(n) \rfloor} \left \lfloor \frac n{p^k} \right \rfloor$ times. See [here](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf) for a proof (of the complexity; the formula is due to Legendre). If you want to be able to calculate $\Gamma(z)$ for all complex $z$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/algorithm-to-compute-gamma-function).