# Evaluating the Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

So I found out about the gamma function yesterday and I spent a bunch of time trying to evaluate certain values like $0.5!=\Gamma \left(1.5\right)$. I used multiple integration by parts, and in the end I always get $0=0$. How can someone compute gamma function values for all real numbers manually? I want to evaluate the integral by hand without using previous simplified equations for certain values.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some work people could look at?

Comment: There's no good way for general values. At the half integers $\pi$ enters: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: i dont want to use simplified functions, i want to know how to compute the integral by hand, Ethan.

Comment: Is this question focused on $\Gamma(3/2)$ or is it supposed to be more general?

Comment: its more general, i want to figure out how to evaluate the function for all real values.

Comment: Have you seen the solutions for things like $\Gamma(1/4)$?

Comment: And if so, you should make it more clear that you want to evaluate the Gamma function for any value.

Comment: Also, to reply to someone, you need to use the @ symbol.  For example, above, you wanted to ping Ethan, so you should type @EthanBolker

Comment: ok @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: You will need numerical methods. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/algorithm-to-compute-gamma-function

Comment: i read something about using the error function, but i cant see how i can apply it here. @EthanBolker

Comment: @DavidSousa First use $\Gamma(3/2)=\frac12\Gamma(1/2)$.  Then, in the integral definition of $\Gamma(1/2)$, make the substitution $x=t^2$ and apply the error function.

Comment: ok ! thank you @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: Might I mention, if you are intending this for $\Gamma(x)$ with $x\in\mathbb Q$, including more than just $\Gamma(1/2)$, then you might want to make this more clear in you question, else it'll likely get closed as a dupe.

Comment: In general, $\Gamma\left(\,z\,\right)$ is  evaluated $\texttt{numerically}$ with $\texttt{Lanczos Formula}$ as explained in [Numerical Recipes, page 257](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html#).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, the sad truth is that there are no known closed forms of the Gamma function for irrational values.

So, if you wanted to approximate the Gamma function for irrational values, presumably by hand, you might wish to implement the following limit formula, a consequence of the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem).

$$\Gamma(s)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n^s(n!)}{s^{(n+1)}}$$

Where we use the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) to denote $s^{(n+1)}=s(s+1)\dots(s+n)$.

As an example,

$$\Gamma(1/2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n(n!)}{(1/2)^{(n+1)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n(n+1)4^{n+1}(n!)^2}{(2n+2)!}$$

Approximating with $n=9$, one finds that

$$\Gamma(1/2)\approx1.70264$$

Which is pretty close to $\sqrt\pi=1.77245$.

Anyways, to the fun stuff!

It's easy to see by integration by parts that

$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$

And thus,

$$\Gamma(3/2)=\frac12\Gamma(1/2)$$

From there, I recommend browsing through [these answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215352/why-is-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi).

A perhaps more useful formula might be

$$\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi s)}$$

A variety of proofs from the integral definition may be found from [One-line proof of the Euler's reflection formula](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76399/91465).  However, this formula provides no light on how to evaluate other values, such as

$$\Gamma(1/3)=\frac{\pi^{2/3}2^{2/3}}{3^{1/12}\operatorname{agm}(1,3^{1/4}2^{-1/2})^{1/2}}$$

$$\Gamma(1/4)=\frac{2^{1/2}\pi^{3/4}}{\operatorname{agm}(1,2^{-1/2})}$$

where $\operatorname{agm}$ is the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) defined by

$$\operatorname{agm}(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\\a_0=x,~g_0=y\\a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+g_n}2,\quad g_n=\sqrt{a_ng_n}$$

This is the closest thing to a closed form one can provide for rational values that are not halves of integers.

Portions on how to find values at such values are given in [this PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf).

To find the values of $\Gamma(1/2)$ and $\Gamma(1/4)$, note that

$$\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}~\mathrm dt$$

Setting $x=y=\frac12$, we find that

$$\Gamma(1/2)^2=\int_0^1t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}~\mathrm dt$$

Let $t=u^2$ to get

$$\Gamma(1/2)^2=2\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

This may be solved either geometrically (consider the arc length formula applied to a circle) or with a trig substitution, and it ultimately yields

$$\Gamma(1/2)^2=\pi\\\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$$

For $\Gamma(1/4)$, let $2x=y=\frac12$ to get

$$\frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}\sqrt\pi=\int_0^1t^{-3/4}(1-t)^{-1/2}~\mathrm dt$$

Let $t=u^4$ to get

$$\frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}\sqrt\pi=4\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}$$

This is a [complete elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind), which gives

$$\frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}\sqrt\pi=4\mathrm K(i)=\frac{2\pi}{\operatorname{agm}(1,\sqrt2)}$$

Applying the reflection formula,

$$\Gamma(3/4)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi/4)\Gamma(1/4)}=\frac{\pi\sqrt2}{\Gamma(1/4)}$$

$$\Gamma(1/4)^2=\frac{2^{3/2}\pi^{3/2}}{\operatorname{agm}(1,\sqrt2)}$$

$$\Gamma(1/4)=\frac{2^{3/4}\pi^{3/4}}{\operatorname{agm}(1,\sqrt2)^{1/2}}$$

By useing $\operatorname{agm}(ax,ay)=a\operatorname{agm}(x,y)=a\operatorname{agm}(y,x)$, the above may be rewritten as

$$\Gamma(1/4)=\frac{2^{1/2}\pi^{3/4}}{\operatorname{agm}(1,2^{-1/2})^{1/2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for all the work that you put into righting this ! Im curious how did Euler reach to that formula ? I cant find a proof of it. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean this one?$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi x)}$$If so, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76399/91465)

Comment: yes that one @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: @DavidSousa Well, one approach involves the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Reflection_Formula).