# Is there a method to compute $\Gamma(e)+\Gamma(\pi)$?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

Find
$$\Gamma(e)+\Gamma(\pi)$$
I am wondering if there is a method to calculate these nubmers or using the definition is the only way.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this has a closed-form answer?

Comment: I just want to see if there is any.

Comment: I can see no reason to think there is a simpler form.  Even $\Gamma(1/3)$ has no known simpler form.

Comment: Do you want numerical approximations? If so then see [Algorithms to compute Gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19236/272831).

Comment: Approximation with 20 correct digits: $\frac{-383+774 \pi +319 \pi ^2}{-1263+696 \pi +43 \pi ^2}$